# Getting 404 on any text file (including robots.txt) with nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, http-status-code-404

I recently moved my CentOS 7 machine from an Apache web server to an nginx web server, and I'm still working out various issues as I learn the in's and out's of nginx. One issue I have stumbled upon is that text files, such as robots.txt, appear to be unaccessible in my public web root directory.

My server block configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root         /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    index        index.php;
    access_log   /var/www/example.com/logs/example.com_access.log;
    error_log    /var/www/example.com/logs/example.com_error.log error;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location /reports {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files          $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass       unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param      SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include            fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page 404 /var/www/html/404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /var/www/html/50x.html;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        #access_log off;
        #log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I am confused about why text files would be inaccessible. I figured this was a problem with me using PHP, but I couldn't determine what might be blocking access to the file.

I also can't check my log files (yet) because this server block doesn't seem to be writing to my logs, but that's in [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/735704/nginx-not-logging-errors-to-log-files).

What could be going on here?

Comment: Deleted answer because it didn't answer your question.  Is the mime.types file included in the http block?

Comment: @AaronMason I don't believe so, as far as I know I haven't specified anything about that nor do I have any files (as far as I know) that are mime.types.

Comment: Did you check SELinux settings?

Comment: @warren I did, I had to move my nginx server blocks to `/var/www/` in order to get SELinux to (more easily) recognize them as web server directories. This was an issue in the past, but as far as I know, SELinux should be labeling the directory correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I restarted nginx and the problem was solved. No idea what caused it as my other domain's .txt files were working.

`service nginx restart;`